# How to find and remove unnecessary theme scripts?

Tags: theme-development, optimization

When I load my website, I see many java scripts and css loading and slowing my website. Many of them I know I'm not using, like fonts, extra theme css from a template that I'm not using, icons and so on.

I've tried to locate them in functions.php but no success. Can I just remove the files from the server, or should I disable it somewhere else?

Comment: If your theme is ready made then you need to check register-scripts file in your theme where all scripts and styles sheet file included and remove it as per your requirement.

Comment: @PratikPatel Not every theme is going to have a 'register-scripts' file. Nor will they necessarily register scripts and styles all in one place. Only fool proof way to find this stuff is to look through every file or contact the author.

Answer (score 1):

You should locate all `wp_register_script` instances (they can be incuded in core, plugin, theme, anywhere) and in your `functions.php` you can deregister them

```
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'my_scripts_method' );
function my_scripts_method() {
    // if you want to exclude built-in jQuery
    wp_deregister_script('jquery');
}
```

All scripts that can be enqueued by Wordpress are listed (there are handles of each) in [codex](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_enqueue_script/)

Comment: Make sure, `add_action()` is called with a high enough priority, that all scripts will be registered by the time the function is called